# Django File-Transfers Save to New File for Each User

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to upload files using Django-filetransfer and I was wondering how to import the username to use as the name of the file the uploads are saved in. Right now I'm using User.username, but that is invalid. I guess the big question is how to access a user's attributes from models.py. Below is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, UserManager

class UploadModel(User,models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='./uploads/'+str(User.username))


    @property
    def filename(self):
    return self.file.name.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
```

**UPDATED:**
app/upload/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, UserManager

def uploadmodel_file_upload_to(instance, filename):
    return 'uploads/%s/%s' % (instance.user.username, filename)

class UploadModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.user')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=uploadmodel_file_upload_to)
```

TemplateSyntaxError at /upload
Caught DatabaseError while rendering: column upload_uploadmodel.user_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "upload_uploadmodel"."id", "upload_uploadmodel"."user...

Comment: Why does UploadModel inherit from User ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model attributes are officially defined when Python parses models.py code. You should **use a callback for [upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)**, to be generate the upload file path using the user related instance, for example:

```
def uploadmodel_file_upload_to(instance, filename):
    return 'uploads/%s/%s' % (instance.user.username, filename)

class UploadModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.user')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=uploadmodel_file_upload_to)
```

Comment: I put that code in models.py and got "NameError: name 'uploadmodel_file_upload_to' is not defined" in the console.

Comment: You didn't paste it right (i tested this code). Please post your updated models.py and the traceback. Probably, you did not paste the uploadmodel_file_upload_to definition **before** the FileField definition which refers to it. Thus, the NameError.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for your help. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Right, so either drop the UploadModel table and run syncdb again, either put your old code back and 0) paste the definition of uploadmodel_file_upload_to in your code **before** UploadModel class and 1) change the FileField's upload_to value to uploadmodel_file_upload_to. (I asked why your model inherits from User [not very sound] but you didn't answer) In my code, i fixed your model which didn't make any sense and did not validate in Django 1.3.1.

Comment: Alright, that is running, but it lets me choose from every user on the site. Is there a way to make it automatically save to a folder labeled with the username of the logged in user?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you open another topic for your other question ? Also, please close this question.